# JavaFX KeyEvents are delayed when using robot.moveMouse()

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, delay, keyevent

I am trying to write some kind of first person view 3D game in JavaFX and the movement works pretty good so far.

I'm using JavaFX's built-in shape and PerspectiveCamera classes to render the image to the scene.

But there is an input lag of around 1-2 seconds for all key events.

**The lags only appear:**

- once the program is switched to **full-screen** (even if switched back to windowed they are still there, but not when the program was just started)
- and the **camera is rotated using the mouse** shortly before pressing/releasing a button

e.g.: I press W to move forward and simultaneously move the mouse. If I release W now the player would still move forward for 1-2 seconds.
Without moving the mouse it does not happen.

This is how the input is tracked:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> keyPressed(e));
scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> keyReleased(e));
```

and (for keyReleased(e) it's the same just with "false")

```
private void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getCode().toString() == "W") w = true;
    if (e.getCode().toString() == "A") a = true;
    if (e.getCode().toString() == "S") s = true;
    if (e.getCode().toString() == "D") d = true;
}
```

For the camera movement i use this function:

```
private void mouseMovement(){
    if(primaryStage.isFocused()){
        mxdelta = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - centerx;
        mydelta = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - centery;

        // Rotate Camera
        cry += mxdelta * sens; // cry = camera rotation around y-axis
        crx -= mydelta * sens; // crx = camera rotation around x-axis

        // move curser back to the center of the screen
        robot.mouseMove(centerx, centery);
    }
}
```

If I remove **"robot.mouseMove(centerx, centery);"** everything works fine. Also if i control the camera movement via arrow keys there are no lags either.

The whole game loop is packed in JavafX's AnimationTimer which gives a stable framerate.

Another small observation: As the program is just launched there are many small stutters. As soon as I switch to full-screen the program runs butter-smooth (despite the input lag of course. But the mouse has no input lag at all).

I can post the full code if needed or upload a video if the problem isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that running the whole **main/game-loop in another thread** apparently **fixes the problem**. There is no input lag anymore and the stutters are gone too.

In case there is someone who is interested in my solution, here it is:

First I packed all the stuff from the game-loop in a function "mainloop()", which looks roughly like this:

```
public void mainloop(){
    mouseMovement(); // <- full function is in the question above
    updatePosition();
    collisionDetection();
}
```

Then I created a **new thread** and put only the **mainloop()** in it:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mainloop();}
        });
    }
};
t.setDaemon(true);
```

Finally the thread is called using an **AnimationTimer**:

```
new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override public void handle(long now) {
        t.run();
    }
}.start();
```

I am not sure if this is an efficient way to solve this problem, but it seems to be working.